# Nominatim geojson

Tags: openlayers, geojson, nominatim

I'm newbie in openlayers, but I have tried to add geojson from nominatim to vector layer

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=wien&polygon_geojson=1&format=json'
})
});
```

My problem is: Uncaught TypeError: geometryReader is not a function

Answer (score 1):

So the TypeError you reference above typically happens when the GeoJSON data you provide lacks a recognized "type" attribute for the features.

More than likely when the reader attempts to read the features it looks at the "type" attribute of each feature - it MUST be one of the following:

```
GeometryCollection
LineString
MultiLineString
MultiPoint
MultiPolygon
Point
Polygon
```

Of course, the data from nominatim ought to be valid geojson - but perhaps there's a record it doesn't recognize for some reason or something.